# What can I do when distinct isn't an option on joins?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working on a pretty large dataset and running into an issue right now that I'm not sure is solveable with the current approach. I am fine posting this as I didn't come up with the initial example, but have been tasked with picking it up. Reworking the logic at this point would be a pretty big step.

The project runs reports on a data warehouse, but to keep things more friendly, I created an example to illustrate the issue I'm running into.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test_customers2 (
    id              integer PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name      varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    last_name       varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    newsletter      integer NOT NULL,
    vipmember       integer NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test_customers2 VALUES(1, 'Reed', 'Richards', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO test_customers2 VALUES(2, 'Johnny', 'Storm', 0, 1);
INSERT INTO test_customers2 VALUES(3, 'Peter', 'Parker', 1, 0);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test_purchases (
    id        integer CONSTRAINT firstkey2 PRIMARY KEY,
    cid       integer NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test_purchases VALUES(1, 1);
INSERT INTO test_purchases VALUES(2, 2);
INSERT INTO test_purchases VALUES(3, 2);
INSERT INTO test_purchases VALUES(4, 3);

SELECT 
    COUNT(distinct c.id) as "Total Customers"
    ,COUNT(distinct p.id) as "Total Sales"
    ,COUNT(distinct p.id)::decimal/COUNT(distinct c.id)::decimal as "Sales per customer"
    ,SUM(c.newsletter) as "Subscribed"
    ,SUM(c.newsletter)::decimal/COUNT(c.newsletter)::decimal as "Pct Subscribed"
    ,SUM(c.vipmember) as "VIP"
    ,SUM(c.vipmember)::decimal/COUNT(c.vipmember)::decimal as "Pct VIP"
FROM test_customers2 c
    INNER JOIN test_purchases p ON c.id = p.cid
```

When you execute the SELECT at the end, you get the results:

```
3 | 4 | 1.33... | 2 | 0.50... | 3 | 0.75...
```

The problem is, because of the join, It's throwing off my results, because I'm really looking for these results:

```
3 | 4 | 1.33... | 2 | 0.66... | 2 | 0.66...
```

The distinct helps the unique values, but the boolean ones (literally an int in this case, not designated as boolean) don't work with that approach since they're only optionable values will be 1, 0, or null. I think I might need sub queries for that, but aside form the dip in performance, it'll be a bit hit to have to rewrite a LOT of code. Is there any other better approaches that I might be missing?

Comment: don't see any `group by`. you sure you don't need a grouping result?

Comment: a group by the customer ID would get me results broken out per customer instead of overall. I'm pretty 50/50 on if this is doable given the current structure we have in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're performing a join merely to bring columns from separate tables into your row set -- you're not actually making use of the relationship between the two source tables, *nor do you want to do*.  It makes sense overall only because you want to relate aspects of the **aggregate** data, and *that's* the data that you should be joining.

I'd suggest computing the single-table statistics in separate inline views / CTEs, and then (cross) joining the two single-row results to obtain another single row from which to perform your ultimate selections.  Something like this, for example:

```
SELECT 
    c.c_count as "Total Customers"
    ,p.p_count as "Total Sales"
    ,p.p_count::decimal/c.c_count::decimal as "Sales per customer"
    ,c.nl_sum as "Subscribed"
    ,c.nl_sum::decimal/c.c_count::decimal as "Pct Subscribed"
    ,c.vipsum as "VIP"
    ,c.vipsum::decimal/c.c_count::decimal as "Pct VIP"
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      count(*) as c_count,
      sum(newsletter) as nl_sum,
      sum(vipmember) as vip_sum
    FROM test_customers2
  ) c
  CROSS JOIN
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS p_count FROM test_purchases
  ) p
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to join. None of your logic requires matching of the 2 tables. Here is the query in MSSQL (sorry I don't know Postgres) but I think you can translate.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as "Total Customers",
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test_purchases) as "Total Sales",
    CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test_purchases) AS DECIMAL) / COUNT(*) as "Sales per Customer",
    SUM(c.newsletter) as "Suscribed",
    CAST(SUM(c.newsletter) AS DECIMAL) / COUNT(*) as "Pct Suscribed",
    SUM(c.vipmember) as "VIP",
    CAST(SUM(c.newsletter) AS DECIMAL) / COUNT(*) as "Pct VIP"
FROM test_customers2 c
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably more "flexible":

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(c.id) as "Total Customers"
    ,SUM(p.total_sales) as "Total Sales"
    ,SUM(p.total_sales)::decimal/COUNT(c.id)::decimal as "Sales per customer"
    ,SUM(c.newsletter) as "Subscribed"
    ,SUM(c.newsletter)::decimal/COUNT(c.newsletter)::decimal as "Pct Subscribed"
    ,SUM(c.vipmember) as "VIP"
    ,SUM(c.vipmember)::decimal/COUNT(c.vipmember)::decimal as "Pct VIP"
FROM test_customers2 c
    JOIN (select cid, count(*) as total_sales from test_purchases group by cid) p ON c.id = p.cid
```